# Programmatically creating layouts and adding to view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I have to create a complicated layout (A receipt view) using a lot of 
data. Because there can be x amount of charges or payments, this view must be done programmatically.

[image]

I am trying to build reusable layouts that I can attache to different `textview`s or `edittext`s and have them line up.

Broken down it looks something like this:
[image]

Which comes down to 2 basic layouts:

1. A full width (where the text is centered)
2. A Split column

a) where one column takes up 3/4's the view on either the left or right.

b) and the second column takes up 1/4 the view.

Here is my attempt. But I don't seem to be getting it right. 
Here is my error:

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first.

Can anyone help?

```
private ScrollView mScrollView;
private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payment, container, false);
    mScrollView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.svPayment);
    mScrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbPayment);
    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llPayment);
    return view;
}


 public void setupGUI() {


        //RESUABLE LAYOUT 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsFull = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramsFull.setLayoutDirection(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramSmall = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramSmall.setLayoutDirection(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        paramSmall.weight = 0.2f;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramLarge = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramLarge.setLayoutDirection(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        paramLarge.weight = 0.8f;


        // HOLDS THE LEFT AND RIGHT COLUMNS
        LinearLayout columnShell = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        columnShell.setLayoutParams(paramsFull);

    //Small column
        LinearLayout columnSmall = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        columnSmall.setLayoutParams(paramSmall);

    //Large column
        LinearLayout columnLarge = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        columnLarge.setLayoutParams(paramLarge);



        //First get rid of all the views, incase of refresh
        mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();


        TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());

        //CUSTOMER
        textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        textView.setLayoutParams(fullwidth);
        textView.setText("Mary Jane");
        columnShell.addView(textView);

        mLinearLayout.addView(columnShell);


       LinearLayout columnRight = new LinearLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        columnRight.setLayoutDirection(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        //LEFT SIDE (1/4)
        textView = new TextView(getContext());
        textView.setLayoutParams(fullwidth);
        textView.setText("PO: ");
         columnSmall.addView(textView);
        columnShell.addView(columnSmall);

        //RIGHT SIDE (3/4)
        textView = new TextView(getContext());
        textView.setLayoutParams(fullwidth);
        textView.setText("4465465456");

        columnLarge.addView(textView);
        columnShell.addView(columnLarge);

        mLinearLayout.addView(columnShell);     
}
}
```

**fragment_payment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.Views.MasterDetails.PaymentFragment">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbPayment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/svPayment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/COLOR_LIGHT_GREY">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llPayment"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you are not getting "right" then tell what is wrong... it will be waaaay better to use `ListView` or `RecyclerView` (with adapters)

Comment: Looks like using `RecyclerView` might be better approach

Comment: RecyclerView + functionality to switch the viewHolder based on which "View" you want to show in the list. Check out this codepath: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Comment: You're calling `mLinearLayout.addView(columnShell)` twice. And, as everyone has said, there are easier ways to do this.

Comment: Actually, both `ListView` and `RecyclerView` are probably overkill for a small number of items. There's nothing wrong with creating `View`s dynamically and adding them to a container. Especially if the number of items is reasonably small.

Comment: As @MikeM. wrote, you are adding `columnShell` twice to the `LinearLayout`, that's where your error is.

Comment: Yeah, I should've expanded on that comment. I didn't necessarily mean to use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. However, defining the layouts for your rows in XML, and then inflating those as needed, would be less work for you, and less prone to errors like the one you've encountered here.

Answer (score 0):

Why use scrollview with linearlayout, you might have to use listview with two textview as chid, and to add new data just add it into list and notify to adpter, your new data automatically added last of the list.